# Where is the memory which vmware used?

Tags: windows, vmware

I have use vmware. I define 5 gb ram for it.

When look system resources in task manager I see vmware just uses 20 mb.

But when I look in vmware (centos) it uses 2gb ram.

How can I see the real usage?

thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: IIRC, that Task Manager column shows only the physical memory that is actually in active use by the application, not the entire allocation.  You'll need to go into the "details" view and select the column "commit size" to see the total usage.  If VMWare is acting as a hypervisor in this case things get even more complicated.

Comment: in details vmware cover 16mb ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:

http://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf

It says here:

> In order to quickly monitor virtual machine memory usage, the VMware
>   vSphere™ Client exposes two memory statistics in the  resource
>   summary:
>
> Consumed Host Memory
>
> Active Guest Memory
>
> Consumed Host Memory usage is defined as the amount of host memory
>   that is allocated to the virtual machine, Active Guest  Memory is
>   defined as the amount of guest memory that is currently being used by
>   the guest operating system and its applications.

A lot of other information in the article.

Hope this helps.

_Vamsi

Comment: so for vmware 25 mb ram usage is true?

Comment: I guess so. If that is what is says in the active guest memory column..